# html not visible in the index file,but can be seen from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

in this codepen    [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcU75.png): https://codepen.io/Siddharth11/pen/LVQmjN

why dont i see the entire html with the classes.
When I use the browser to check ,i see all the class.Plz see this image of the classes from the browser window.
[image]

Can anyone tell me how will I edit the html,if I wish to ?

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/Siddharth11/pen/LVQmjN
```

Comment: The HTML is changed with javascript, those changes will never be stored back in the actual source file.

Comment: Where do you don't see the classes?

Comment: Thanks for the input.But how do I change the html.lets say the colour code appears on the right side.How do I change it to some other text ? @adeneo

Comment: I dont see them in the html file,but from a browser u can verify the script.(lets say pressing  f12 for firefox) @JonesJoseph

Comment: @jane this was done with D3. If you check the JS, you're gonna see the D3 code creating those SVG elements. What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: The elements aren't present there, hey are being created by the script, So no way you can see them in the HTML file as @adeno said.

Comment: okay. I want to change the content in the txt which appears on the right side as color codes.I will echo some value using php.here in the js,various classes such as slices,labels etc is being used. Anyways,thanks for the input.God Bless @GerardoFurtado

Comment: @jane no worries. An advice: delete this question (or edit it heavily) and post another one, with the tags "JavaScript" and "d3js", asking how to change those texts, and you'll get some help.